# Google Sheets how to lock a row after 1 hour data entry

Tags: google-sheets

I shared a file of Google sheets with my collaborator, and every day he will input the data into the row of Google Sheets, and I want to lock that row after 1 hour after he finishes his work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apps Script for this. Use a [time-driven installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) in a script that protects/locks the sheet.

Your code should be something like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var permissions = sheet.getSheetProtection();
permissions.setProtected(true);
sheet.setSheetProtection(permissions);
```

Comment: I try many times but I can't do it, please help 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XT2yIgy6hfXGqazbJkRL72ceSD9FKLn9bPq94eADl4k/edit#gid=0

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't do it"? Have you tried adding a script to your sheet already? Have you encountered any errors?

Comment: I have no knowledge of scripting and steps. I only know how to use google sheets. But want to write a command that can be input data after 1 hour the row will be a lock? help me, please

Comment: @pakseboylao have you already added the script on your sheet?